# Best approach for creating a reusable object to get users location?

Tags: android, android-fragments, location, google-play-services

I have an app which currently consists of 2 activities. Inside the first activity there is a `Fragment` which itself contains a `MapFragment`. The other activity contains a `ViewPager` which holds two fragments, one of which is also a `Fragment` that itself holds a `MapFragment`. In both fragments that contain the `MapFragment` I need to request the users current location (only once, when the user requests it). To get the users location I'm using Google Play Services Location API. What would be the best approach here for avoiding duplicate code in two of the mentioned fragments containing a `MapFragment` (managing connection errors etc)?  Should I create an `IntentService` or try to manage with a plain java class or are there better ways that I'm currently not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make a custom [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and call [getLastLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#getLastLocation%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient%29) when requested by user - then store that location in a field and make a getter for that field.

Comment: This gave me an idea of creating a custom `Fragment` which the two `Fragment`s containing a `MapFragment` would extend. Are there any downsides to this approach compared to creating a custom `Application`?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the common code a component (probably a POJO) and use a dependency injection framework (probably [dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger)) to inject it where I need it.

If using a DI framework is a bit over the top for your case you should still go for the component approach and write you own (close to trivial) logic to provide it where needed.

This will also become a must when it comes to unit testing, because you are then able to stub / mock the location provisioning.